# The specified resource does not exist on getting all entities of a table from azure table storage

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

> I m working on a reactjs web app, where in I need to connect to a
> table from azure table storage. However I was able to createEntity
> using sas token by below code

```
const client = new TableClient(tableUrl, tableName, new AzureSASCredential(sasToken));

 try {
          const entity = {
            partitionKey: `${partitionKey}`,
            rowKey: id,
            id,
            type: partitionKey,
            isActive: true,
            name: "Car" 
          };
      
          await client.createEntity(entity)
        } catch (error: any) {
          console.log(error)
        }
```

> But when I try to listEntities, Im getting error as if I do not use sas token
> **Error: Shared Access Key authentication is not supported in the browser** for below code

```
 const credential = new AzureNamedKeyCredential(storageAccountName, accountKey);
 const client2 = new TableClient(`https://${storageAccountName}.table.core.windows.net`, tableName, credential);

        try {
            const entities = client2.listEntities();

            for await (const entity of entities) {
                console.log(entity);
            }
        } catch (error: any) {
            console.log(error)
        }
```

and if I use sas Token then **404 (The specified resource does not exist.)**  for below code

```
    const client1 = new TableClient(
            `${tableUrl}${sasToken}`,
            tableName
        );

     try {
            const entities = client1.listEntities();

            for await (const entity of entities) {
                console.log(entity);
            }
        } catch (error: any) {
            console.log(error)
        }
```

> How to perform all crud operations in Reactjs without the above errors

```
const client3 = new TableClient(tableUrl, tableName, new AzureSASCredential(sasToken));

        try {
            const entities = client3.listEntities();

            for await (const entity of entities) {
                console.log(entity);
            }
        } catch (error: any) {
            console.log(error)
        }
```

Comment: `and if I use sas Token then 404 (The specified resource does not exist.) for below code` - can you share how the [`url`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/data-tables/tableclient?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-data-tables-tableclient-url) property of table client look like?

Comment: @GauravMantri  `${tableUrl}${sasToken}` is mentioned above, may I know what exactly you asked for?

Comment: I'm not sure if creating a client using `const client1 = new TableClient(
            `${tableUrl}${sasToken}`,
            tableName
        );` will produce the right client (I may be wrong though). That's why I wanted to see the actual URL of the client after it has been instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

> But when I try to listEntities, Im getting error as if I do not use
> sas token Error: Shared Access Key authentication is not supported in
> the browser for below code

This is expected behavior. Shared access key authentication is only supported in server-side JS (Node) and not client-side JS. You would need to use either SAS token or Azure AD based authentication if you want to use the SDK on the client side.

From the documentation [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/data-tables/tableclient?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-data-tables-tableclient-constructor):

[image]

Comment: so what exacly should the above code look, since I tried both ways and encountered different errors

Comment: Something like - `const client = new TableClient(tableUrl, tableName, new AzureSASCredential(sasToken));`. Make sure that your SAS token has proper permissions to execute queries otherwise you will get 403 error.

Comment: now as per your code, Im getting this error- 501 (Not Implemented)    The requested operation is not implemented on the specified resource

Comment: Please edit your question and add the updated code towards the bottom of the original question. Also include the SAS token you are using (just obfuscate the sig part before sharing).

Comment: added the updated code for 501 error, sastoken is sv=2021-06-08&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacupiytfx&se=2023-01-12T23:16:26Z&st=2023-01-12T15:16:26Z&spr=https&sig=

Comment: SAS token looks ok. Does your table URL look like `https://account-name.table.core.windows.net`?

Comment: const tableUrl = `https://${storageAccountName}.table.core.windows.net/${tableName}`;

Comment: Aah...please get rid of the table name from the table URL. It should be just `https://${storageAccountName}.table.core.windows.net`.

Comment: now getting this error after removing tablename from url   -  RestError: Error sending request: Failed to fetch

Comment: Trace the request in browser's dev tools may be?

Comment: its just a request url, not sure what I should check here